# What is the merit to using the negedge clock in verilog?

Tags: verilog

Now I'm trying to understand the merit what we using the negedge clock in verilog.
I came across as the below verilog code in the google.

```
module negedgecapture
   ( 
    input              clk,
    input              rst_n,
    input              din,
    output wire        dout
    );

   reg           neg_dout    ;
   assign dout = neg_dout;

   always @(negedge clk or negedge rst_n)
     if (~rst_n) neg_dout <= 0;
     else neg_dout <= din;

endmodule
```

and in case, as I know, the setup time is at least required time the data to become stable before the clock edge.
and hold time is at least required time the data to become stable after the clock edge.

But I don't know what benefits are in there? why we use those kinds of Technic?

Comment: Are you asking about setup & hold time? Please clarify your question.

Comment: i2c, spi, mdio, etc will have one side output on one edge so the other side can sample on the opposite.  Change on falling read on rising, or change on rising, read on falling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular advantage to using the falling edge of a clock as opposed to the rising edge to clock a register. In fact, most designs I've worked on using a rising edge for everything. There are a few cases where I've seen the negative edge used though:

1. When working with an external interface that uses a negative for some reason. I seem to recall that a long time ago i.e. in the days of bipolar TTL logic, the I/O drivers may be asymmetric with regards to rise and fall time, with the fall time being faster. In some cases, this behaviour got grandfathered into the interface design.
2. On some older ASIC designs, designers would switch from one clock edge to the other when moving between blocks to avoid clock skew issues. However, since then, layout tools have got better at using managing clock skew, so this process is no longer used.
3. On DDR (double data rate) interfaces, data changes on both the positive and negative clock edges. You'll see this in LVDS based I/O and DDR memory interfaces.

Comment: Thanks but, what about the point of view at the hold time violation ? If I use above code, then is there any merit?

Comment: Can you let me know more about "On some older ASIC designs, designers would switch from one clock edge to the other when moving between blocks to avoid clock skew issues." Technic?

Comment: @gander3 This technique was used before good static timing analysis tools and clock tree synthesis tools were available. At that time, clock skew was pretty controllable within a block of logic (physically confined to a rectangular region in layout) but somewhat unpredictable between modules. So designers would use an opposite edge flop at the inputs to their blocks to correct for clock skew. The tools are better these days, and clock speeds are much faster, so I haven't seen this technique used since the late 1990s.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing on a posedge, reading would be useful on a negedge. That would save one full clock cycle on a read operation.

Negedge clock operation is also used in testbenches, to avoid race condition between DUT and Testbench, since both are driven at different clock edges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there any example to exercise that?